# Need PowerShell Script in NuGet to install selected DLLs from Package into a VS Project

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

Can anyone please explain me the detailed steps to include in a PowerShell script for installing selected DLLs from a package into a VS project, based on the References in a project (say from the .csproj file)?

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone please explain me the detailed steps to include in a PowerShell script for installing selected DLLs from a package into a VS project, based on the References in a project (say from the .csproj file)?

As we know, there is a PowerShell script `install.ps1` that can be included in the package, which is by convention named and located in tools folder.

Download a NuGet package, for example, [Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/10.0.3). Open the install.ps1 file in the package with notepad, the scripts should begin with the following line:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
```

> - `$installPath` path to where the project is installed
> - `$toolsPath` path to the extracted tools directory
> - `$package` information about the currently installing package
> - `$project` reference to the EnvDTE project the package is being installed into

See [Running PowerShell scripts during NuGet package installation and removal](https://everydaylifein.net/netframework/running-powershell-scripts-during-nuget-package-installation-and-removal.html) for more detail.

Then after above scripts, you can find the below scripts, which used to install the dll from a package into a VS project:

```
$newRef = $project.Object.References.Add("PathToMyDLL")
```

Note: `Install.ps` will only be invoked if there is something in the `\lib` or `\content` folder, not for a "tools only" package.