# How to get the content of a file during NuGet package install

Tags: nuget-package, powershell-5.0

I have a nuget package solution which installs just fine. I now need to modify the target project's `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` file to add some code.

I have an `Install.ps1` script so I'm adding my powershell script to this. As I'm building it up as I go, what it does at the moment is this:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
$content = Get-Content $project.ProjectItems.Item("Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs")
```

The error it is giving me is this:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.At 
C:\git\Testing\packages\Standards.Testing.1.0.6694.30974-beta\tools\Install.ps1:2
char:1
+ $content = Get-Content $project.ProjectItems.Item("Properties\Assembl ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

The intent is to load the content of the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file and check it for certain content, then modify it and write it back.

What I don't understand is why it won't read the content of that file into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was incorrectly trying to reference the path of the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. I didn't realise that the parameters to the script were providing everything I need and that other posts have referenced a scary-looking class which contains all the required information.

SO containing information about script parameters:
[Need PowerShell Script in NuGet to install selected DLLs from Package into a VS Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945188/need-powershell-script-in-nuget-to-install-selected-dlls-from-package-into-a-vs/45956706#45956706)

Linked from that post is this page which details the available information about a nuget install:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.dte?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2017

My script now looks like this:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

#Update the AssemblyInfo.cs if it has not been updated before
function Get-Append-String {
    $text = ''
    $args[0] | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $text += $_ + "`n"
    }
    return $text
}

function Get-Append {
    $text = ''
    $args | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $text += $_
    }
    return $text
}

function Get-Contains {
    $text = Get-Append-String $args[0]
    return ($text -like $args[1])
}

$query = "*using Xunit;*"
$xunit = "using Xunit;`n"
$comment = "`n// xUnit configuraiton...`n// MaxParallelThreads limits the number of threads which xUnit will use to run tests`n[assembly: CollectionBehavior(MaxParallelThreads = 8)]`n"

$path = $project.FullName + '\..\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs'
$content = Get-Content -Path $path
$content = Get-Append-String $content

if ( ($content -like $query) -eq $false ) {
    $content = $xunit + $content + $comment
    Set-Content -Path $path -Value $content
}
```